# How to show a different value in a input box in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have this HTML form which is showing some unrealistic numbers in the input boxes. By the way, the data I get in the input boxes is coming from the database. I would like to show in the input box a "NA" instead of that 99999999.9999 value. I don't know if there's an if statement that can help me to solve this problem.

```
 <form id="new-inventory-item-form" action="#" formaction="process" data-ajax="false">
         <h3>  Assets</h3>

    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <label for="longitude">Longitude</label>
        <input type="number" name="" id="longitude" value="9999999.99999999">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <label for="size">Latitude</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="latitude" value="9999999.99999999">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: At what point do you consider a value to be 'unrealistic'?

Comment: hi man... I want to help but I don't understand what you need... can you be more specific?

Comment: If that is the number that always comes back from your database, just test for it and if true replace it with "N/A".

Comment: @LeoJavier what I want is to replace the 9999999.99999999 value with NA so I was just wondering if there's like an if statement or something that I can decide what to print if that is the value from the database. AlexGM I wish it was that easy but unfortunately is not the same value always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your scenario, it appears you need to validate Latitude and Longitude from db or may be from a user input and display 'NA' if they don't qualify. The best thing for you would be to validate the values through a regex in your js, something like this :

```
$("#btn").click(function()
{  
  $('.lat').each(function()
  {    
          if (!IsMatch('^-?([1-8]?[0-9]\.{1}\d{1,6}$|90\.{1}0{1,6}$)',$(this).val())) {           
            $(this).val("NA");
        }
  });

  $('.long').each(function()
  {  
          if (!IsMatch('^-?([1-8]?[0-9]\.{1}\d{1,6}$|90\.{1}0{1,6}$)',$(this).val())) {           
            $(this).val("NA");
        }
  });

});

function IsMatch(exp, value) {
   var exp = new RegExp(exp); return exp.test(value);
}

Lat : <input class="lat" type="text"/>
Long : <input class="long" type="text"/>
<button id="btn">Validate</button>
```

js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/u4hghL9c/2/

Comment: Thank for your answer. However, I was thinking what is the purpose of using regex if the number will be always 9999999.999999 so I can just use if with that correct? So I made a simpler jsfiddler. I just want to validate if val=90 then it would output NA so I modified the jsfiddle to this: http://jsfiddle.net/u4hghL9c/3/ But when I click validate it doesn't change it to NA

Comment: Fixed your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/u4hghL9c/4/ . But be aware that this might be only one instance where you are checking for a specific value. At some point of time you would need to rely on regex for displaying the correct values.

Comment: Great! that's what I wanted. I understand about the regex and of course it's a great thing to have in that case, but in this case I'm looking for a single value in particular. Thank you for your help!

Comment: is there any way I can use the same function for both inputs?

Comment: Thank you that is awesome. I've notice however that if I have other inputs containing the value 90 inside of the string, e.g. 90834 it changes them to NA. How can I be more specific that only the inputs that have 90? Thanks

Comment: Here's the updated fiddle to change only '90' to NA : http://jsfiddle.net/u4hghL9c/7/ .

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your want to change the attribute `value`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Here is how you set it. 
The same works for getting the attribute - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

`if (parseFloat(node.getAttribute('value')) === 999999.9999) {
   node.setAttribute('value', 'N/A'); 
}`

Comment: if node.value equals '99999.99999', node.value = 'NA' ELSE true value. Thats;a what I want

Comment: Check out the edited answer. Do you want something different?

Comment: There is some mess in the code. First, you have two different types of input - number and text. If you use number, you don't need parseFloat. Second, I made a typo(which I corrected) in if statement. Don't blindly copypaste the code, check it first. And third, yes, you have to choose your elements with some of the built in functions getElement(s)By.